# Set persistent environment variable in cmd file for python

Tags: windows, python-3.x, subprocess, environment-variables

If I use os.environ, it sets a temporary variable.
I'm trying to set persistent one using cmd file like this

```
setx /M VARIABLE VALUE
```

If I run a script and check the result, it fails:

```
import os
import subprocess

setup = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'setup.cmd')
subprocess.run(setup, shell=True)
for key, value in os.environ.items():
    print (key, value)
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  In Windows, every process gets its own environment block.  There's no way for a child process to edit the environment block of its parent.

Comment: And  so, the fact that I have administrator rights does not help?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: Persistent environment variables are stored in the registry. To create persistent environment variables you need to update the registry. You cannot change the environment after the fact, though.

Comment: Having administrator rights allows you to use the `/M` switch of setx.exe. This sets a persistent environment variable for all users. Omit `/M`  to set it just for the current user. setx.exe broadcasts a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to top-level windows. (The cmd.exe shell, and typically python.exe, do not own any windows; the console window belongs to conhost.exe.) On receipt of this message, a process can elect to reload its environment from the registry. Most don't, but Explorer does, so you'd have to respawn your script from Explorer.

Comment: Even if you update the process environment from the registry (e.g. by calling the undocumented shell32 function `RegenerateUserEnvironment(LPVOID *pNewEnvironment, BOOL bUpdateCurrentEnvironment)`), Python only uses the `os.environ` copy of the real process environment and won't see the changes.